# Rust: error: lifetime may not live long enough

Tags: rust

I am new to rust. Whenever I try call this function, I get an error: lifetime may not live long enough. The error message further says that - argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`.

```
fn get_sizes(dir: &str, listings: &HashMap<&str, Vec<Vec<&str>>>, sizes: &mut HashMap<&str, i32>){
    sizes.insert(dir, 0);
}
```

I want to set the value for key dir to 0 in hashmap sizes.

Comment: Do you mean `&'static str`? If you're not using static `&str` you may need to switch to `String`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exactly what the compiler tells you (even though you did not put the whole message): the lifetime associated with the borrow of `dir` may be shorter than the one required by `sizes`. This is because the actual lifetimes are implicit, and all generic.

The solution is very simple: explicitly enforce equality of the lifetimes.

```rust
fn get_sizes<'a>(
    dir: &'a str,
    listings: &HashMap<&str, Vec<Vec<&str>>>,
    sizes: &mut HashMap<&'a str, i32>,
) {
    sizes.insert(dir, 0);
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2a4d070ac4e3bf6422164d42f05f25f).

Answer (score 1):

If you read the full error

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
2 | pub fn get_sizes(dir: &str, _listings: &HashMap<&str, Vec<Vec<&str>>>, sizes: &mut HashMap<&str, i32>){
  |                       - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`                     - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'2`
3 |     sizes.insert(dir, 0);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
  |
2 | pub fn get_sizes<'a>(dir: &'a str, _listings: &HashMap<&str, Vec<Vec<&str>>>, sizes: &mut HashMap<&'a str, i32>){
  |                 ++++       ++                                                                      ++
```

You'll see that you have to enforce `dir` lives longer than the key in `sizes` with explicit lifetimes.
Rust even gives you a suggested fix to that problem.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn get_sizes<'a>(
    dir: &'a str,
    listings: &HashMap<&str, Vec<Vec<&str>>>,
    sizes: &mut HashMap<&'a str, i32>,
) {
    sizes.insert(dir, 0);
}
```

Comment: Even though, in all generality, you want `'b` to outlive `'a`, and not just `'b = 'a` as in my answer, since `&'a T` is covariant in `'a`, it's actually the same; so it's just simpler to have a single lifetime.